# No keyboard or mouse during Windows 10 reInstall

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, windows-installation

I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 onto my computer after resetting it since it was full of junk. I reset the computer via settings and am now trying to reinstall it, but neither my keyboard nor mouse will work or show up on the screen. The keyboard works completely fine in the BIOS, but I can’t test the mouse since my BIOS doesn't have mouse support. The moment the Windows logo appears my mouse and keyboard turn off. I have been running Windows 10 on this PC for years now and it worked perfectly.

- My USB Wi-Fi Dongle works during the install.
- My [Gigabyte motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G31M-ES2L-rev-1x#ov) is limited to USB 2.0.

I have tried:

- Using different USB Ports, Front panel and on the back
- Using a different USB mouse

Also I here is my BIOS's Integrated Peripherals screen since I have seen people messing around with it and gotten it to work:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rioD.jpg)

Specs:

- CPU: C2Q Q6600
- GPU: GT 710
- RAM: 4GB DDR2
- mobo: GIGABYTE GA-G31M-ES2C (REV 1.0)
- HDD: WD Blue 320GB 7200RPM

I fixed the issue. Instead of going we the reinstallation 'program' Windows gives you after you reset. I used a USB drive with the Windows installation media on it. It seems to be working fine so far. I am at 31% on copying files.

Comment: Updated, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: There are no Windows 10 drivers available from the manufacturer as per https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G31M-ES2L-rev-1x#support-dl-driver and changes in Windows 10 may prevent you from successfully reinstalling.  I would suggest using a PS/2 keyboard and mouse to see if that allows you to get past the USB problem.

Comment: I will see if I can get my hands on a PS-2 mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself, I installed window from a USB drive after creating the installation media using the Media Creation Tool. I still do not know what the problem was, maybe windows wiped the drivers for the mouse and keyboard?

Here is the download link the to the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10). It requires a minimum of an 8GB USB Drive (I just used a 32GB Class 10 SD Card with a USB 2.0 Reader.